# i face an error everytime i start a new project of color.xml file

Tags: colors, android-studio-3.5

i'm facing a problem everytime i start my project of content is not allowed in prolog while facing an error in values/colors.xml when i try to correct it manually then i face an another error can anyone help?

i have tried sorting this error manually then i face another error of android resource compilation failed mipmap-anydpi- v26/ic_launcher_round.xml 
mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml 
Android resource compilation failed 
Android resource compilation failed 
mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml
drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml

PK     A                 META-INF/ PK     A (M��?   T      META-INF/MANIFEST.MF�M��LK-.�
K-*��ϳR0�3����-�I�M�+I,
�d��Z)�%��b�µ���r�r PK     A               org/ PK     A

i'm expecting normal functionality instead of this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmnJB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of cache is not clear, Then this problem is occurs
**Go to File ==>   invalidate caches/restart** 
Your problem will solve. 
if the problem is not solved By this
Also, update your Android Studio and SDK